# How to compile Vertx Groovy verticle using "override"

Tags: groovy, vert.x

I am trying to get a simple Groovy verticle compiled but the compiler trips on the fact that it cannot use the "override" keyword.Any suggestion on how i can get the verticles compiled using the "override" keyword?

**compile fail.. due the fact it cannot use override**

```
class AppStarterGroovy extends Verticle {
    override def start() {
       ...
   }
}
```

*>> Groovyc: unexpected token: override*

**compile fail.. due the fact that the return type of Verticle is different**

```
class AppStarterGroovy extends Verticle {
    def start() {
       ...
   }
}
```

*>> Groovyc: The return type of java.lang.Object start() in com.AppStarterGroovy is incompatible with void start() in org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle
. At [8:5]*

**compiles ok..**

```
class AppStarterGroovy extends Verticle {
    void start() {
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there's no `override` keyword in Groovy, that's an error in the documentation and  should just be removed.

But if this is Groovy, and you're extending `Verticle`, you should extend `org.vertx.groovy.platform.Verticle`

https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/vertx/groovy/platform/Verticle.groovy

Which has `def start()` in it

Comment: No worries :-) the documentation being wrong doesn't help ;-)